# Why does scanf require &?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read a number from stdin. I don't understand why `scanf` requires the use of `&` before the name of my variable:

```
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
```

Why does `scanf` need the address of the variable?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It needs to change the variable. Since all arguments in C are passed *by value* you need to pass a pointer if you want a function to be able to change a parameter.

Here's a super-simple example showing it:

```
void nochange(int var) {
    // Here, var is a copy of the original number. &var != &value
    var = 1337;
}
void change(int *var) {
    // Here, var is a pointer to the original number. var == &value
    // Writing to `*var` modifies the variable the pointer points to
    *var = 1337;
}
int main() {
    int value = 42;
    nochange(value);
    change(&value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just finding this and learning myself.  Have a follow up if anyone reads this....the & is giving you access to the stored location so that you can change the value?  That's the way I understand it anyway....

Comment: @Dan Yes, you're right. Although you're completely right, if it's still a bit scary to you I recommend you to watch "Ashley Mills" C video tutorials on YouTube on pointers.

Answer (score 12):

C function parameters are *always* "pass-by-value", which means that the function `scanf` only sees a copy of the current value of whatever you specify as the argument expression.

In this case `&i` is a pointer value that refers to the variable `i`. `scanf` can use this to modify `i`. If you passed `i`, then it would only see an uninitialized value, which (a) is UB, (b) is not sufficient information for `scanf` to know how to modify `i`.

Answer (score 7):

It's not needed.

```
char s[1234];

scanf("%s", s);
```

Works just fine without a single `&` anywhere. What `scanf` and company need are *pointers*. To let it modify a particular variable, you pass the address of that variable. For a few types that happens by default. For others, you use `&` to take the address (get a pointer to that variable).

Answer (score 5):

Because otherwise it would only be altering a copy rather than the original.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf()` stores values, so it needs a place to store them.
This is done by providing the addresses (in pointers) of
where to store the values using `addressof` or &(ampersand) operator.

Answer (score 2):

scanf requires the addressOf operator (&) because it takes a pointer as an argument. Therefore in order to pass in a variable to be set to a passed in value you have to make a pointer out of the variable so that it can be changed.

The reason a pointer must be passed to scanf is that if you just passed a variable, you wouldn't be able to directly alter the variable within scanf, so you couldnt set it to the value read in by scanf.

Hope this helps.