# Error when running C-program after first input

Tags: c

The program shuts down after I enter the first input

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int biology,chemistry;
    printf("\nEnter marks for maths");
    scanf("%d",biology);
    printf("\nEnter marks for tech1");
    scanf("%d",chemistry);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Use &biology and &chemistry

Comment: Just about any [beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will tell you what you need to know. Please find and read one.

Answer (score 5):

C function parameters are always "pass-by-value", which means that the function `scanf` only sees a copy of the current value of whatever you specify as the argument expression.

If you passed `biology`, then it would only see an uninitialized value. On the other hand `&biology` is a pointer value that refers to the variable i.e `scanf` can use this to modify `biology`.

The `scanf`would need to be modified as follows

```
scanf("%d", &biology);
scanf("%d", &chemistry);
```

To understand this in detail read [Why does scanf require &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597606/why-does-scanf-require)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing incorrect arguments to scanf() calls. You must pass the *address* of the variables (see [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)'s documentation) to match `%d` format.

```
scanf("%d", &biology);
...
scanf("%d", &chemistry);
```

You should also check the return code to see if the `scanf()` calls succeeded.