# Process terminated with status -1073741510 Error

Tags: c, codeblocks

So I decided to learn C on my own and was using CodeBlocks and decided to try out a basic program that asks to enter two integers then prints out the sum but CodeBlocks keeps giving me an error that I am unable to figure out how to fix. It brings up the first enter you integer but as soon as I enter it stops working and gives me an error.

I tried resetting the compiler to default

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int int1, int2, sum;

    printf("Enter first integer\n");
    scanf("%d", int1);
    printf("Enter second integer\n");
    scanf("%d", int2);
    printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597606/why-does-scanf-require

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does scanf require &?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597606/why-does-scanf-require)